# How to create a Mongoose method to write images to cloudinary

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloudinary

So I have MEAN stack application (car sales) that requires me to allow users to upload multiple images to a MongoDB back-end. I have chosen to to upload the images to [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/), then on successful upload, create a new document with the image urls returned by Cloudinary.

I'm fairly new to NodeJS / Mongoose so I am unsure how I actually achieve what I want to do. Here is what I have so far:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');

var AdSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    sellerEmail: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    expiresAt: { type: Date, default: new Date(+ new Date() + 28 * 24 * 60 *     60 * 1000) },
    adTitle: String,
    price: Number,
    currency: String,
    phoneNo: String,
    county: String,
    make: String,
    model: String,
    year: Number,
    engineSize: Number,
    fuelType: String,
    bodyType: String,
    otherMake: String,
    otherModel: String,
    transmission: String,
    miles: Number,
    milesKm: String,
    taxExpiry: String,
    testExpiry: String,
    sellerType: String,
    description: String,
    imageUrls: Array,
    mainImage: Number
});

AdSchema.methods.uploadImages = function (images) {
var ad = this.toObject();
if (images.length) {
    images.forEach(function (image) {
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(image.path).then(function (result) {
            ad.imageUrls.push(result.secure_url);
            //the images are uploaded to cloudinary as expected and the urls are pushed to imageUrls, but what do I do now? 
            // not sure what to return when images have been uploaded
        });
    });
} else {
    cloudinary.uploader.upload(images.path).then(function (result) {
        ad.imageUrls.push(result.secure_url);
        // not sure what to return when image has been uploaded
    });
    }
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Ad', AdSchema);
```

server.js (snippet)

```
//I want to call method above and on success, save the ad
ad.uploadImages(req.files.images, function() {

    ad.save(function(err, savedAd) {
        //I am fine with this part
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I figured it out myself:

I added callback to the method:

```
AdSchema.methods.uploadImages = function (images, callback)
```

then on successful upload I returned the callback:

```
return callback(null, ad);
```

then called it like this:

```
ad.uploadImages(req.files.images, function(err, callback) {
    if(err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: 'there was an error creating your ad. Your card has not been charged'
        });
    }
    //save ad
});
```